# How to use Python's multiprocessing library to parallelize a for loop that iterates a depth array?

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, performance, multiprocessing

I work with well log data that has different values related to different depths. Very often I need to iterate over the depths, performing calculations, and storing these values in a previously created array to create new well logs. It is something equivalent to the example below.

```
import numpy as np

depth = np.linspace(5000,6000,2001)
y1 = np.random.random((len(depth),3))
y2 = np.random.random(len(depth))

def fun_1(y1, y2):
    return y1 + y2

def fun_2(y1, y2):
    return sum(y1 * y2)

result_1 = np.zeros_like(y1)
result_2 = np.zeros_like(y2)

for i in range(len(depth)):
    prov_result_1 = fun_1(y1[i], y2[i])
    prov_result_2 = fun_2(y1[i], y2[i])
    
    result_1[i,:] = prov_result_1
    result_2[i]   = prov_result_2
```

In the example, I go depth by depth using the y1 and y2 values to calculate provisory values prov_result_1 and prov_result_2, which I then store in the respective index of result_1 and result_2, generating my final result_1 and result_2 curves when the loop ends. It's easy to see that, depending on the size of the depth array and the functions I apply at each depth, things can get out of hand and this code can take several hours to complete. Keep in mind that the y1 and y2 arrays can be much larger and the functions I apply are much more complex than these.

I would like to know if there is a way to use Python's multiprocessing library to parallelize this for loop. Other answers I've found here on StackOverflow don't directly translate to this problem and always seem to be much more complicated than they should be.

One option I imagine would be to divide the depth by the number of processors and do this same for loop in parallel, something like:

```
num_pool = 2
depth_cut = (depth[-1]-depth[0])/num_pool
depth_parallel = [depth[depth <= depth[0] + depth_cut],
                  depth[depth >  depth[0] + depth_cut]]
y1_parallel = [y1[depth <= depth[0] + depth_cut],
               y1[depth >  depth[0] + depth_cut]]
y2_parallel = [y2[depth <= depth[0] + depth_cut],
               y2[depth >  depth[0] + depth_cut]]
```

Only more generic. Then I would put the pieces of data into parallel processing, perform my calculations, and then concatenate everything again.

Comment: In your single-threaded example, it seems like the depth array is not related at all to y1 or y2, and could be removed without changing the result. Is depth relevant to the problem?

Comment: Your basic idea to break up the work in chunks that can be handle by separate processes on separate cores is certainly the most straightforward way to try. Of course, if the actual computation isn't always equally hard for the different parts (there may be multiple execution paths through your code), that may not be optimal. Another way would be to break up the work in far smaller chunks and keep feeding those to worker processes until they're all done. Whatever you try, keep in mind that multiprocessing adds a lot of overhead - only expect improvements for *large* datasets.

Comment: However, your question as it currently stands is either not specific enough (provide an example of what you tried at least), or akin to asking for libraries / frameworks. Neither is suited to StackOverflow. Please try a strategy and ask about the result here, or pick a solution out there, and possibly do the same. (for example, your problem sounds like it might be more suited to get commonly used libraries to perform the parallelisation for you, using either multiple cores or GPU)

Comment: @NickODell no, it's not. It just controls the index of the arrays, but it could be replaced by y1 or y2.

Comment: @Grismar I did not try anything because I don't know how to work with parallelization. I wrote the first thing that came to my mind, but I'm open to any suggestions. I don't see why this question is not suited for stack overflow.

Comment: In that case, I recommend having a look at [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you don't know how to work with parallelisation, there's lot of tutorials out there to get you started with any specific library - SO is the right place to come if you try something but can't get it to work with the documentation or tutorials alone.

Comment: @LucasOliveira Parallelization questions are hard to answer in the abstract, because so much of whether a parallelization technique is useful depends on the specifics of the problem. The standard advice is to use [multiprocessing.map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html), but depending on your problem, that might not provide a speed up. It really depends on what fun_1 and fun_2 actually do. That's why I asked about the purpose of `depth`. I don't understand your explanation.

Comment: That being said, almost certainly, if your example really is something like what you've shown you should insted try to *use numpy vectorized operations to do what you are trying to do before even thinking about parallelization (which often doesn't help with numpy)*. You shouldn't be using a for-loop here at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could then :

- use `multiprocessing` library,
- create two parallelize functions to deal separately with chunks

The general idea is to create a separate process for each function, and deal with chunks one by one inside each function-process.

To my mind this is a simple way to keep control on differential treatment speeds related to both functions.

**Proposed code**

```py
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool

def fun_1(args):
    y1_i, y2_i = args
    return y1_i + y2_i

def fun_2(args):
    y1_i, y2_i = args
    return sum(y1_i * y2_i)

def separate_process(func, y1, y2, num_pool):
    """Separated process to deal chunks with one function at a time"""
    # Create a pool of workers
    pool = Pool(num_pool)
    # Divide the data into chunks for treatment 
    # (good thing to do with large datasets)
    
    ### Assuming len(y1) = len(y2)
    chunk_size = len(y1) // num_pool
    chunks_y1 = [y1[i:i + chunk_size] for i in range (0, len(y1), chunk_size)]
    chunks_y2 = [y2[i:i + chunk_size] for i in range (0, len(y2), chunk_size)]

    # Apply function for each chunk in parallel
    results = pool.map(func, zip(chunks_y1, chunks_y2))
    # Avoid 'float' exception
    results = [result.tolist() if isinstance(result, np.ndarray) else [result] for result in results]
    # Close the pool
    pool.close()
    # Wait for the process to finish to keep control
    pool.join()

    # Concatenation : chunks treatment strategy is not supposed to be visible at the end
    return results

depth = np.linspace(5000, 6000, 2001)
y1 = np.random.random(len(depth))
y2 = np.random.random(len(depth))

num_pool = 2

fun_1_res = separate_process(fun_1, y1, y2, num_pool)
fun_2_res = separate_process(fun_2, y1, y2, num_pool)

print(len(fun_1_res))
### 3
print(len(fun_2_res))
### 3
```

**Chunks results concatenation :**

```py
def concatenate_chunks(fun_x_res):
    return sum(fun_x_res, [])
    
fun_1_res = concatenate_chunks(fun_1_res)

# Final length (supposed to be 2001)
print(len(fun_1_res))
### 2001
```

**Note :**

We could widen the perspective and calculate `fun_res_1` and `fun_res_2` in two separate processes too.

So you should have in this last case :

`2 main processes + 2 X 2 sub-processes (in separate_process) = a total of 6 processes`

A powerful computing environment is required for this.

Comment: I'm not sure what happened, but I got this error:
RuntimeError:
An attempt has been made to start a new process before the current process has finished its bootstrapping phase. This probably means that you are not using fork to start your child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module:
if __name__ == '__main__':
freeze_support()
...
The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.

I'm not sure if this is a problem with my pc or with the code.

Comment: It works well on my configuration. Do you change something ? python 3.10 for me. And tested on `online-python` interpreter, it works too

Comment: No, it's probably my pc. I'll check in other pc. But thanks!